# Как сделать так, чтобы человек мог оставлять заявки на сайте которые были бы видны остальным?

Tags: php, wordpress, форма

Есть сайт на `wordpress`. Подскажите, как можно сделать так, чтобы человек, который заходит на сайт мог оставлять заявки (через форму), которые бы не отсылались по e-mail админу, а были видны всем остальным пользователям на определенной странице. Может быть есть готовый плагин или функционал для этого?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По функционалу похоже на гостевую книгу, можно использовать что-то типа [Gwolle](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/gwolle-gb/) например.

Comment: а как записи этой гостевой книги включить в поиск, чтобы можно было найти интересующую в записях информацию?

Comment: @Вася думаю, что это тема для отдельного вопроса.

Comment: задал отдельный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/778635/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B5

Answer (score 2):

Это обычные стандартные комментарии.