# Как устроить поиск по записям в гостевой книге?

Tags: wordpress, поиск, wordpress-плагины

Есть сайт на `wordpress` с установленной гостевой книгой [Gwolle](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/gwolle-gb/)
Интересует вопрос как можно организовать поиск по информации, хранящейся в записях (если их будет более 1000)?

Comment: Да хоть 100 тысяч. Записи гостевой книги - скорее всего, посты кастомного типа. Поиск по ним производится так же, как и стандартный поиск WordPress - посредством WP_Query() с параметром s=